# How can I call methods of inherited classes just by calling the same method of base class?

Tags: c++, oop

Like in Game engines for example in XNA the update function is called automatically again and again. I want to know how i can achieve this in c++.

For ex:

```
class base
{
void Update();
};

class child1: public base
{
void Update();
}

class child2: public base
{
void Update();
}

void main()
{
base *obBase = new base();
obBase->Update(); /*This should call Update of Child1 and Child2 classes how can I do  this*/
}
```

Comment: By "This should call Update of Child1 and Child2 classes how can I do  this", do you mean, that you need to call `Update` of all objects with type `Child1` and `Child2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make it virtual:

```
class base
{
    virtual void Update();
};
```

This will provide polymorphic behavior

And I assume you ment:

```
base *obBase = new child1(); //or new child2();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access all instances of a derived classes of a base class.

What you need to do is to have some kind of a container, which will store all your objects of type `Child1` and `Child2` and then, when you decide, iterate through this container and call `Update`.

Something like:

```
SomeContainer< base* > myObjects;
// fill myObjects like:
// myObjects.insert( new ChildX(...) );
// ...
// iterate through myObjects and call Update
```

To be able to do this, you need to make `Update` a virtual function.

To prevent (potential) memory leaks, use smart pointers, instead of `base*`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use polymorphism, something like this:

```
Base* obj1 = new Child1();
Base* obj2 = new Child2();

BaseManager* manager = new BaseManager(); //A class with a data struct that contains instances of Base, something like: list<Base*> m_objects;
manager->add(obj1); //Add obj1 to the list "m_objects"
manager->add(obj2); //Add obj2 to the list "m_objects"

manager->updateAll(); //Executes update of each instance in the list.
```